# ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh

Although This has been discussed, but still i am not able to solve this. Here is a quick review of what i did and how i got into the trouble:

Installed Ubuntu 12.10, installed ssh, `sudo apt-get install ssh`. The favorite ssh was working fine and connected by using `ssh localhost`. I removed Ubuntu, increased the partition and again installed Ubuntu. Again I fired `sudo apt-get install ssh`, it showed me

```
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
```

When I given command , `ssh localhost`, it gave me error as:

```
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: Can you retry after doing `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo iptables -L`? And `sudo netstat -l`?

Comment: Installing `openssh-server` resolved problem

Comment: Thank you, @Mousavi.  That was all I needed.  Funny this is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Fire this command:

```
sudo iptables -L
```

If you see that no traffic is allowed (i.e. no specific rules), then run the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ssh -j ACCEPT
```

this command tells the system to allow incoming connections to port 22...and usually should solve your dilemma, specifically for `ssh` / `sshd`.

UPDATED as of July 31,2016:
iptables have nothing to do with ssh as an application, but on other hand, functions as router in allow the traffic to port 22. When using iptables, the system actually understand 'ssh' however, it's a shortcut within command line but, really, it's actually `iptables INPUT -p udp -dport 22` while --dport means "destination port" (ssh uses port 22). This probably caused some misconception on seeing 'ssh' as if it's an appication, but really '22' as port.

Comment: There are many sections coming such as Chain ufw-reject-forward, Chain ufw-reject-input, Chain ufw-reject-output... So which section need to refer to check?

Comment: Sounds like your traffic is being capped, then go ahead and add that command line and reboot.

Comment: I did the same and rebooted , same issue :(

Comment: Also I did this    mohnish@PC:~$ ps ax | grep ssh
 1742 ?        Ss     0:00 ssh-agent
 2677 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
mohnish@PC:~$ ps ax | grep sshd
 2679 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto sshd    Does this help?

Comment: No response from which sshd but able to /usr/bin/ssh when used which ssh...

Comment: Hi, thanks for ur response, u were right about the earlier one. After re-booting I used apt-get install ssh, and then it began the usual installation process smoothly.Thanks Bro :)

Comment: Glad to know you got this tackled down!  What you can do is to close your question as solved (by click a check sign on the response so that way this question get closed as solved and wouldn't stay in stack for others to review.  :)  Cheers.

Comment: Sry for late response, did the same.. thanks :)

Comment: How exactly did the issue get solved?

Comment: I was referring to closing this question as solved on this discussion - which user234202 has done.  Meanwhile, the issue was to tell iptable to accept port so that the connection via ssh is possible; after rebooting the system.

Comment: I ran into this same issue on a Bitnami VM for Wordpress on Ubuntu 14.0.2. If you are by chance using a bitnami VM, ssh has been disabled for security purposes. Read more about how to enable ssh here in this article: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Virtual_Appliances_Quick_Start_Guide#How_to_enable_sshd.3f

Comment: Still not working for me. I have ufw installed and ssh is allowed in the iptables. even i have tried disabling the firewall.

Comment: @Braiam restart your wireless devices 'sudo ifconfig wlan0 eth0 restart' Make sure you can ping the Pi via it's IP address as well. , so  Check your router network settings then martch a static IP for the Pi.
Enable ssh and chck its status as well 'sudo service ssh status'
You should be good after sudo reboot

Comment: @Kizito that's unhelpful. This answer should solve the problem presented on the question. The thing is that there's absolutely anything that points to the root cause of the problem *in the question itself*.

Comment: @Kizito iptables have nothing to do with ssh as an application, but on other hand, functions as router in allow the traffic to port 22.  When using iptables, the system actually understand 'ssh' however, it's a shortcut within command line but, really, it's actually `iptables INPUT -p udp -dport 22` while `--dport` means "destination port" (ssh uses port 22).  This probably caused some misconception on seeing 'ssh' as if it's an appication, but really '22' as port.

Comment: For me, all I had to do was sudo apt-get install openssh-server