# Cannot SSH locally from Mac to Ubuntu 16.04 Server (running as Hyper-v guest on Server 2012R2)

Tags: 16.04, server, ssh, openssh

I've looked just about everywhere for a solution but I have yet to find one.

Here's my problem:
I try and connect to my Ubuntu Server via SSH from my Macbook Pro within my LAN with:
`ssh nextcloud@192.168.0.18`, but I keep on getting this no matter what I try:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.18 port 22: Connection refused
```

If I try connecting again with `ssh -vvv nextcloud@192.168.0.18` for more detail, here's what I get:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.18" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.18 [192.168.0.18] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.0.18 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.18 port 22: Connection refused
```

As far as firewall status and rules go, here's how I have it configured:

[image]

Also, here is my `sshd_config` if that helps:

[image]
[image]

Any help would be really appreciated as I am stuck at the moment.. If there's any other helpful info I can provide, let me know.

Comment: On your ubuntu server, what do you get it you try `ssh localhost`?

Comment: Is the ssh server running ?

Comment: are you sure your SSH service is running? `systemctl status sshd.service`

Comment: @NickSillito -- `ssh localhost` returns: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTNyq9hZ_NiMlB5Ynp2a01WZzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @bodhi.zazen -- Yes it does appear to be running: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTNyq9hZ_NieWxWSVRieExBWDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @hamiheim -- Yes it does appear to be running: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTNyq9hZ_NieWxWSVRieExBWDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you ping the server ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen -- Yes, I can ping perfectly fine.

Comment: post the exact ssh command you ran.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen -- Which ssh command do you mean exactly? If you are referring to the command to connect to the server I used: `ssh nextcloud@192.168.0.18`

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools `{}` to make it look nice.

Comment: Do you have anything in either /etc/hosts.allow or /etc/hosts.deny?

Comment: For clarity, is there a user "nextcloud" on the server?

Comment: What version of MacOS are you running. I use ubuntu server and a Mac. I am running Sierra 10.12.4, and when I use ssh on the Mac, it reports the ssh version as `OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0` which looks a newer release than the version you are using?

Comment: @SpasSpasov -- I would be copy-pasting, but I can't ssh into the machine or copy from the vm. If you have any ideas on how I can, please do inform me.

Comment: @NickSillito -- 
- Everything in both those files is commented out.
- Yes nextcloud is a user on the server w/ sudo privileges
- I'm running MacOS 10.12.3 -- I'll see if there is a system update available

Comment: Is it possible Windows firewall to block the connection in any way? Also can you ssh from Windows?

Comment: @SpasSpasov -- I tried to ssh from PuTTy on my PC running Win 7 and no luck there. Also, both windows firewall on the Hyper-v server and Win 7 PC are turned off.

Comment: I was trying to find [**this question**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/739164/ssh-connection-refused) few days ago but today I found it. There is described similar issue and the solution is reinstallation of the ssh server: `sudo apt-get purge openssh-server; sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.

Comment: @SpasSpasov -- I used that question's thread to troubleshoot earlier. No luck on the command you suggested unfortunately..