# ssh: connect to host xxx.yyy.com port 22: Connection refused - Unable to access my server via SSH

Tags: ssh

I am using Ubuntu 22 and SSH is active. UFW is inactive. I have a single key pair and I have stored the pub on the server under `authorized_keys`. There was already a key there from another computer of mine. I am in my private network. From this network I can access the server with my older computer via SSH.

So you would think that everything is set up correctly. Especially as the basic setup for SSH is relatively self-explanatory and as a beginner I have never had any problems establishing an SSH connection.

**Note:** I can access my GitHub account with the same pub key. So the key and my SSH work.

**Question:** What else could be causing this error?

**ssh -vvvv username@ip.address.of.server output**

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/me/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "xxx.yyy.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup xxx.yyy.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to xxx.yyy.com [1.1.1.1] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address 1.1.1.1 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host xxx.yyy.com port 22: Connection refused
```

**Output: systemctl status sshd.service**

```
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-03-08 09:51:37 CET; 4h 42min ago
       Docs: man:sshd(8)
             man:sshd_config(5)
   Main PID: 2847372 (sshd)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18688)
     Memory: 1.7M
        CPU: 13ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/ssh.service
             └─2847372 "sshd: /usr/sbin/sshd -D [listener] 0 of 10-100 startups"

Mär 08 09:51:37 ttsbnb50 systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Mär 08 09:51:37 ttsbnb50 sshd[2847372]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Mär 08 09:51:37 ttsbnb50 sshd[2847372]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Mär 08 09:51:37 ttsbnb50 systemd[1]: Started OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
```

**output: sudo netstat -anp | grep ssh**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2847372/sshd: /usr/ 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2847372/sshd: /usr/ 
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     HÖRT         42144    4471/systemd         /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     HÖRT         43365    4493/gnome-keyring-  /run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     VERBUNDEN     16223127 2847372/sshd: /usr/  
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     HÖRT         5563534  1563240/ssh-agent    /run/user/1000/keyring/.ssh
```

**Output: `ls -la ~/.ssh` from the computer where cant connect to my server**

```
drwx------  2 me me 4096 Mär  3 15:12 .
drwxr-x--- 32 me me 4096 Mär  8 14:42 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 me me   51 Dez 29 22:48 config
-rw-------  1 me me  464 Apr 18  2023 id_ed25519
-rw-r--r--  1 me me  111 Apr 18  2023 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-------  1 me me 1784 Jan  8 10:27 known_hosts
```

**Output: `cat ~/.ssh/config`**

```
Host github.com
 Hostname ssh.github.com
 Port 443
```

**Output: `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config | grep -v ^#`**

```
Include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf

Host *
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

**Output: `ls -la /etc/ssh`**

```
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 Mär  8 09:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 143 root root  12288 Mär 12 06:25 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 505426 Jan  2 17:54 moduli
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   1650 Nov 23  2022 ssh_config
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Nov 23  2022 ssh_config.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   3254 Jan  2 17:54 sshd_config
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Jan  2 17:54 sshd_config.d
-rw-------   1 root root    505 Mär  8 09:51 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    175 Mär  8 09:51 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root    399 Mär  8 09:51 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     95 Mär  8 09:51 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw-------   1 root root   2602 Mär  8 09:51 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    567 Mär  8 09:51 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    342 Dez  7  2020 ssh_import_id
```

**Output: `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config`**

```
Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
#   UserKnownHostsFile ~/.ssh/known_hosts.d/%k
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

Comment: @user68186 I add it via UI from my Serverprovider the key. And i updated my question and put the output -vvvv to it. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @user68186 I add the output from `systemctl status sshd.service` to the question. thx

Comment: @user68186 `Status: Inaktiv`

Comment: @user68186 I can't check it now because I've just left. But I wrote that I never had problems logging in via SSH with my other computer. This computer is a company computer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ssh connection refused](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739164/ssh-connection-refused)

Comment: @user68186 As it is a company computer, it is of course possible that another backup software is blocking the port. But I have no problem communicating with GitHub via ssh. But my knowledge is really too limited to check that. For completeness, I have added the output from netstats to my question.

Comment: Something in the path drops the connection. That's what connection refused means. It could be on the remote end, the client or anywhere in between.

Comment: @user68186 Hello! Im add the output from the `ls -la`

Comment: .config and your pubkey have an extra read permission that mine don't, probably "anyone". Try turning those off and then retry the connection. In other words I think @user68186  is on the right track. Ssh is picky about permissions.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you ! I will set the authorisation to just (`-rw-------`) and try again. I wonder then why github works and my server does not. Is it then due to the setting on the other side (i.e. server or github)? I will let you know if it has worked. Probably not until tonight.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at another computer and there it's set like yours, so this might not be it after all.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Thank you, almost. Then I'll have a look at my other computer and see what the authorisations are there.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I thank you in advance and our colleague user68186 for your time and effort.

Comment: @user68186 I just took out an old computer (ubuntu 16) and generated a pair of keys there and put the pub on the corresponding server. And with the old computer I can also log in to my server. it looks like there is something configured on my work computer that is preventing me from establishing an ssh connection.

Comment: @user68186 I add the content to the question. thx

Comment: Good Morning @user68186. Thank you for your effort.  I updated my question.  On to the last attempt. I have read that it might help to reinstall open ssh. but I'd better wait for your answer.

Comment: @user68186 I came across something very interesting that I can't explain. I went into the VPN with my work computer and then tried again to connect to my server via SSH and it worked. But I don't know why?

Comment: @OrganicMarble It might be interesting for you to know.
I came across something very interesting that I can't explain. I went into the VPN with my work computer and then tried again to connect to my server via SSH and it worked. But I don't know why?

Comment: @user68186 It is a work VPN. And SSH only works when I am in the VPN. I could try to establish an SSH connection via my private VPN. But I suspect it will only work via the work VPN.

Comment: @user68186 No, the server is my private server. The computer is from my work. The VPN network is also from work.